# How to print the '| |' in determinant using traditionalform?

Tags: notebooks, formatting, traditional-form

Suppose I have a matrix `mat={{a,b},{c,d}}`, if I want to display the determinant of `mat` with the two vertical lines, then how do I do it? I want to have `Det[mat]==0//TraditionalForm`, but instead of showing a matrix with curly bracket replaced by vertical lines, it evaluates it directly and outputs`ad-bc=0`. How to surpress the evaluation?

Comment: Something like: `(Det[x] == 0 // HoldForm) /. x -> mat // TraditionalForm`?

Comment: @Xavier yeah that is close, although it will give both vertical lines and bracket at the same time.

Comment: Yes, these respectively come from the `TraditionalForm` of `Det` and `MatrixQ` objects. What about `Grid[mat, Dividers -> {{1 -> True, (Length@mat + 1) -> True}}] == 
  0 // TraditionalForm` then?

Comment: Alternative, probably not as fast solution: `DispDet[M_] := Row[{StyleBox["|", SpanMaxSize -> \[Infinity], FontSize -> 20], Grid[M], 
 StyleBox["|", SpanMaxSize -> \[Infinity], FontSize -> 20]}] // DisplayForm;`, then `mat // DispDet`